Reset TabBar to Default Tab on Navigation When Using go_router for Screen Transitions
In my Flutter project, I have a BottomNavigationBar with four screens/pages. On the third screen, I use a TabBar with two tabs: "Request" and "Resolve."
Additionally, there's a floating action button (+ icon) that navigates to a "New Request" screen.

Issue:

When I am on the "Resolve" tab and click the floating action button to create a new request, I navigate to the "New Request" screen. After submitting the new request, I return to the third screen, but instead of returning to the "Request" tab, it returns to the "Resolve" tab.

Requirement:

I need to ensure that after submitting a new request, the app should automatically switch to the "Request" tab when returning to the third screen.

Additional Context:

I am using go_router: ^14.2.0 for navigation.

In my main.dart file, I define the named routes using go_router.

I have a separate file for the BottomNavigationBar, and I use context.go('/home') to navigate back to the bottom navigation bar screen.

Solution Attempt:


I have tried to solve this issue by passing initialIndex to the TabController in the initState() method of the RequestListScreen. However, it doesn't work as expected.
 late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("selectedIndex>>> ${widget.selectedIndex}");
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
    super.initState();
  }

i have try multiple solution but it is not working.
class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavBar({super.key});

  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  // Create a list of pages for the IndexedStack
  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    const DocumentScreen(),
    const UploadScreen(),
    const RequestListScreen(selectedIndex: 0),
    const ProfileScreen(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    _selectedIndex = index;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isShowBottomNavBar = Provider.of<Bottomnavbarprovider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedIndex,
        children: _pages,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: isShowBottomNavBar.isBottomNavBarVisible
          ? BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: _selectedIndex == 0
                      ? const Icon(
                          SmartFinDoc.file_text,
                          size: 24,
                        )
                      : const Icon(
                          SmartFinDoc.newdoc,
                          size: 24,
                        ),
                  label: 'Document',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: _selectedIndex != 1
                      ? const Icon(
                          SmartFinDoc.upload_1,
                          size: 24,
                        )
                      : const Icon(
                          SmartFinDoc.upload,
                          size: 24,
                        ),
                  label: 'Upload',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: _selectedIndex != 2
                      ? const Icon(
                          SmartFinDoc.document_1,
                          size: 24,
                        )
                      : const Icon(
                          SmartFinDoc.request,
                          size: 24,
                        ),
                  label: 'Requests',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: _selectedIndex != 3
                      ? const Icon(
                          SmartFinDoc.user_rounded_1,
                          size: 24,
                        )
                      : const Icon(
                          SmartFinDoc.user_rounded,
                          size: 24,
                        ),
                  label: 'Profile',
                ),
              ],
              currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
              selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
              unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
              showSelectedLabels: true,
              showUnselectedLabels: true,
              onTap: _onItemTapped,
              iconSize: 24,
              selectedFontSize: 12,
              unselectedFontSize: 12,
              selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Inter-SemiBold',
                  fontSize: 12,
                  color: Appcolors.tabBarActiveTextColor),
              unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  color: Appcolors.tabBarTextColor),
              selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(size: 24),
              unselectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(size: 24),
            )
          : null,
    );
  }
}

This is my BottomNavigationBar file.

GoRoute(
            path: 'home',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const BottomNavBar();
            }),

make naedRoute in main.dart file

Flutter Doctor:

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.22.2 on channel stable at /Users/moin/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 761747bfc5 (2 months ago), 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200
    • Engine revision edd8546116
    • Dart version 3.4.3
    • DevTools version 2.34.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/moin/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15F31d
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.91.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.94.0

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • iPhone 15 Pro Max (mobile)      • 15BA36C7-0DE9-416F-A6CE-A239BE0B6FFA • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-5 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)                 • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.5 23F79
      darwin-arm64
    • Mac Designed for iPad (desktop) • mac-designed-for-ipad                • darwin         • macOS 14.5 23F79
      darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)                    • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome
      127.0.6533.120
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for iPhone 13 pro max. Ensure the device is unlocked and
      attached with a cable or associated with the same local area network as this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for iPhone 13. Ensure the device is unlocked and attached with a
      cable or associated with the same local area network as this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for iPhone X. Ensure the device is unlocked and attached with a
      cable or associated with the same local area network as this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

Please help, I am new to Flutter and need help with an issue I'm facing. I have found a solution, but it is not working.


So, the solution is simple actually. And the problem with your solution is when you move to the 3rd screen. The screen with the tabs doesn't get disposed or killed. And this happens when you're using context.push(..). Basically the new route gets pushed/added on top of the old route. So the action on initState function doesn't get called.
Your solution would be doing some like this -
First move to the 3rd screen, and making the Tab screen wait for user to return to it.
And then, moving the TabController to initial index.
And the sample code will look something like this -
{
  // ...
  await context.push('/new_request_screen`); // Here you can even have a variable and return some result from the 3rd screen.
//And then based on the result, choose if you want the tab to animate or not.
  _tabController.animateTo(0);
}

